# What is the Big O Notation of this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, big-o

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
    arrs1 = list(s1)
    arrs2 = list(s2)

    if all(True if arrs2.count(item) <= arrs1.count(item) else False for 
item in arrs2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I am trying to create a function that can test if a portion of a strings characters (str1) can be rearranged to match another string (str2).

Is this not O(n)?

Comment: No, you are calling `.count` in a loop, which is O(n) thus it is O(N^2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code posted is actually `O(n^2)`:

```
all(True if arrs2.count(item) <= arrs1.count(item) else False for item in arrs2)
```

`all` requires a single pass over the input, yielding `O(n)` for a time complexity. However, on each pass, the number of times `item` occurs in `arrs2` and `arrs1` must be obtained. `count` is `O(n)` in complexity, since the list object must be iterated over as well to find each occurrence of the desired value. The `count` method is called twice, however, it sill approximates to `O(n)` as the average time complexity. Therefore, the complete expression is `O(n)*O(n) => O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Ajax's answer, your code without the `all` statement would look something like this:

```
def scramble(s1, s2):
  arrs1 = list(s1)
  arrs2 = list(s2)

  are_counts_lte = []
  for item in arrs2:
    # this next "count" statement makes it O(n^2)
    if arrs2.count(item) <= arrs1.count(item):
      are_counts_lte.append(True)
    else:
      are_counts_lte.append(False)

  for b in are_counts_lte:
    if b is False: return False
  return True
```

This is clearly *O(n^2)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution with an average time complexity of O(n) you can use `collections.Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
def s(s1, s2):
    c1, c2 = Counter(s1), Counter(s2)
    return all(v <= c1.get(k, 0) for k, v in c2.items())
```